# How to plot a horizontal tree with edges having adjustable length and ending with nuts?

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest, trees

I want to plot trees like these:
[image]

These trees appear in the theory of branching chains in modern probability. But I have no idea how to realize it via latex. Could anyone help on it?

Here are my requirements:

1. The trees need to grow horizontally;
2. The edges can have different length which can be adjusted by myself;
3. Each edge ends with a hollow circle;
4. One tree has bevel edges and the other has square edges.

Thanks in advance...

**EDIT:** Thanks for the comment of @Jasper Habicht. Here is what I tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0.2cm,0) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};},
    grow=0,
    reversed,
    parent anchor=east,
    child anchor=west,
    anchor=west
}
[, l = 2cm
    [, l = 1cm]
    [, l = 2cm
        [ , l = 2cm]
        [ , l = 1cm]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

I expected to get a horizontal tree like the second one in above picture, but it failed and resulted a weird one-line tree... I could not figure out why. And I'm not able to make edges ending with nuts...

Any comments and hints will be appreciated... TIA.

Comment: So, what exactly prevents you from plotting these? Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows what you did so far and where exactly you problem is. Try to only ask one specific question at a time. Since there are different ways to approach this, it is crucial that you help us help you by providing some code to start with.

Comment: @Jasper Habicht Thanks for letting me know this. I have editted my queston and added what I tried. Could you offer more hints for my problem?

Comment: Why was this tagged with every tree package except the one you're using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this (but there exists probably a more elegant way to do thi):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={
    circle, 
    draw, 
    inner sep=1pt,
    edge path={
        \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) 
            |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
    where level={0}{
        draw=none,
        parent anchor=east,
    }{},
    grow=0,
    reversed,
    s sep=0.5cm,
    length/.style={
        before computing xy={l=#1},
    }
}
[{}
    [{}, length=0.5cm
        [{}, length=1.5cm]
        [{}
            [{}, length=3cm]
            [{}, length=2cm]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}

% same code as above, the only difference is -- instead of |- in edge path option:
\begin{forest}
for tree={
    circle, 
    draw, 
    inner sep=1pt,
    edge path={
        \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) 
            -- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
    where level={0}{
        draw=none,
        parent anchor=east,
    }{},
    grow=0,
    reversed,
    s sep=0.5cm,
    length/.style={
        before computing xy={l=#1},
    }
}
[{}
    [{}, length=0.5cm
        [{}, length=1.5cm]
        [{}
            [{}, length=3cm]
            [{}, length=2cm]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Your code is already very elegant!

Comment: Hint: use `if` rather than `where` inside `for tree` to prevent multiplying the number of times the tree is processed. Otherwise you effectively have `for tree={for tree={}}`. It won't harm anything but slows compilation.

Comment: Is there a way to put labels on the above of each edge? Thanks!

Comment: @Dreamer Sure, you can do this as you can do with any other `forest` diagram. Just add `edge label={node[midway, above]{label}}`, for example: `[{}, length=3cm, edge label={node[midway, above]{label}}]`.